# Remove all rows that don't have #3 as the beginning in primary key

Tags: excel, vba

So basically,
I need to remove all records that don't have 3 as the 2nd digit in the primary key field which for example can either look like this

```
#39001
```

Or without the #3

What I want is that all cells that have a non #3 start, their rows be deleted
I came up with the following code,
It removes some non #3, but not all.
I have over 13000 rows to scan

```
Sub keep3()
'
' RemoveNum Macro
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 14000

If InStr(Cells(i, 2), "3") = 2 Then

Else
Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

If you can point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful!

Thanks!

Comment: This is a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552173/must-remove-first-character-of-cell-if-not-3created-loop-never-ends/16552255#16552255

Comment: And its the same person asking the question who you initially provided the answer to :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete a row all the rows below it move up, then you increment "i" which essentially skips the newly moved row.  Try the following instead...

```
Sub keep3()
'
' RemoveNum Macro
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While i < 14000
    If InStr(Cells(i, 2), "3") = 2 Then
        ' Do nothing
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        ' Note - not incrementing i here
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: In condition you could use `If Not Left$(Cells(i, 2), 2) = "#3" Then`, it has better performance

Comment: Another approach to this would have been to have your For loop go from 14000 to 2 Step -1.

Comment: 14000 haha my little atom processor is going haywire

Comment: @dazedandconfused seems like this code is running in an infinite loop or something, because once i run the macro, it doesn't stop running, i waited like 15 minutes...

Comment: yep, when yiu get.to the last row it is going to keep churning.  you will probably need to add a check for blank and exit the loop when found.

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities:

Remove the line that has the `Else`.  I think it is preventing the delete from working in the way you want.  I am assuming that you do not have more than 14000 lines of data....

Or it might be that when you delete the row it messes up the order of the rows that you are running through.

Comment: Wrong. `If ... Then **Do Nothing** Else **Delete Row**`. This is bad but it's not the problem. The problem is about the Delete