# must remove first character of cell if not #3Created loop never ends

Tags: excel, vba

So basically, I need to remove all records that don't have 3 as the 2nd digit in the primary key field which for example can either look like this

```
#39001
```

Or without the #3

What I want is that all cells that have a non #3 start, their rows be deleted I came up with the following code, It removes all, but the macro never stops running..

```
 Sub keep3()
    '
    ' RemoveNum Macro
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    While i < 14000
        If InStr(Cells(i, 2), "3") = 2 Then
            ' Do nothing
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            ' Note - not incrementing i here
        End If
    Wend
    End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: At some point you're probably running out of rows with data.  The blank rows afterward will continuously get deleted and never increment i.

Comment: ok, how do I work around

Comment: If your data does have empty rows, you can add another check in the else case to increment on empty rows. If you don't have empty rows, you could change the while condition to be `Not Cells(i,2) = ""` which will stop any extra unneeded iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Sub keep3()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 14000 To 2 Step -1
        If Mid(Cells(i, 2), 2, 1) = "3" Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Note that the loop is going backwards - this is because when you delete a row, the row below gets pulled up, so your loop can do strange things if you go forwards and then delete a row, as you may skip over the next row that you may have also wanted to delete.  Also, I changed the IF statement as you said you want to delete rows where the 2nd character is a 3.

Comment: Move or add in before wend as well

Comment: I've changed the response, please see above