# Excel crashes while trying to run a loop to delete rows without specific words

Tags: excel, vba

So having a nightmare, the syntax and all is correct but the logic seems to be flawed :S
This code is meant to delete rows that do not contain the words

```
Facility
```

and

```
Government
```

From all cells in Column B, starting from row 2

```
Sub lol()


Dim i As Integer
i = 2
'While i < LastRow  <---- Use for real calc, LastRow calculated beforehand
While i < 4

If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "Facility" Then
    ElseIf Cells(i, 2).Value <> "Government" Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1

    End If

Wend

End Sub
```

Yet somehow, it keeps crashing my excel, I thought it may be because of my atom processor, so I reduced the size of the loop to minimum. 
Yet it still crashes, can anyone see any bugs?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'crashes Excel', do you mean you get a VBA error or a catastrophic Excel crash?

Comment: Excel 2013
Excel is stuck in ''running'' mode, then goes to Not responding, and eventually I have to force close it.

Comment: Didn't you ask pretty much the same question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552173/must-remove-first-character-of-cell-if-not-3created-loop-never-ends/16552255#16552255

Comment: That doesn't work for this problem

Comment: jus have to add a blank cell check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub DeleteRowsBasedOnCriteria()
    Dim i As Long ' instead of integer
    ' always delete from the end
    For i = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If StrComp(CStr(Range("B" & i).Value), "Facility", vbTextCompare) = 0 Or _
            StrComp(CStr(Range("B" & i).Value), "Government", vbTextCompare) = 0 Or _ 
            isEmpty(Range("B" & i)) Then
        Else
            Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete (xlShiftUp)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Just need to add a blank cell check :D

Comment: @Mjall2 so you dont want to delete the empty ones? ive added that

Answer (score 2):

You need to step backwards when deleting rows or the indexing will get mixed up. Also your `ElseIf` logic won't work. Use an `And` instead. Finally, use a `For` loop instead of a While, as it indexes automatically. This is untested, but should work:

```
Sub lol()
Dim i As Integer

i = 2
For i = LastRow to 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "Facility" And Cells(i, 2).Value <> "Government" Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I cant do the thousands of records for calculations, thats why im using i<4
I'm not sure where to put the next i statement

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that I left it out. Try now.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot,
Just a question if the row is deleted, the logic dictates that i is incremented after the End if regardless of the if condition yes? would that not then mean i skip rows because rows shift up when i delete them

Comment: any ideas about the problem, hence why i avoided for loops

Comment: got it fixed, just have to add a blank cell check

Comment: No,  that won't be a problem  because you are stepping  backwards,  as  mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete use Cells(i, 2).Delete(xlShiftUp). Should do it.

And put a VBA.DoEvents() just before the wend so you can break into the program.

I'll try to be a bit more useful! This will work:

```
Sub lol()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    'While i < LastRow  <---- Use for real calc, LastRow calculated beforehand
    While i < 4

    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "" Then Stop

    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "Facility" And Cells(i, 2).Value <> "Government" Then

            Set rng = Cells(i, 2)
            rng.Delete (xlShiftUp)

        Else
            i = i + 1

        End If
        VBA.DoEvents

    Wend

End Sub
```

You see I've added a termination condition with the stop statement and redone the If statement.

Comment: Just improved it a little so you can break in.

Comment: Now its just constantly in "running" mode